# Concatenate dataframes with the same column names but different suffixes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have used pandas merge to bring together two dataframes (24 columns each), based on a set of condition, to generate a dataframe which contains rows which have the same values; naturally there are many  other columns in each dataframe with different values. The code used to do this is:

```
   Merged=pd.merge(Buy_MD,Sell_MD, on= ['ID','LocName','Sub-Group','Month'], how = 'inner' )
```

The result is a dataframe which has 48 columns, I would like to bring together these now (using melt possibly). so to visualise this:

```
           Deal_x        ID_x         Location_x  \... 21 other columns with _x postfix
0        130        5845             A   
1        155        5845             B  
2        138        6245             C   
3        152        7345             A 

         Deal_y        ID_y         Location_y \ ... 21 other columns  with _y postfix
0        155        9545             B   
1        155        0345             C   
2        155        0445             D
```

I want this to become:

```
           Deal        ID        Location \
0        130        5845             A   
1        155        5845             B  
2        138        6245             C   
3        152        7345             A 
0        155        9545             B   
1        155        0345             C   
2        155        0445             D
```

Please how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get rid of the suffixes using `df.columns.str.split` and taking the first split value from each sub-list in the result.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, ...]  # a generic solution for 2 or more frames

for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i].columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[0]
```

Now, concatenate the result -

```
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
df

   Deal    ID Location
0   130  5845        A
1   155  5845        B
2   138  6245        C
3   152  7345        A
4   155  9545        B
5   155   345        C
6   155   445        D
```

Also, if you're interested, use `str.zfill` on `ID` to get your expected output -

```
v = df.ID.astype(str)
v.str.zfill(v.str.len().max())

0    5845
1    5845
2    6245
3    7345
4    9545
5    0345
6    0445
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Assign the result back.

Comment: @MrNemo If it helped, don't forget to vote on, and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is certainly the answer I want, but am getting a strange error.: ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned....    Any ideas?

Comment: @MrNemo Strange, `concat` is great with those misaligned shapes. Please restart your kernel.

Comment: error seems to be occurring here: for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i].columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[0]

Comment: @MrNemo Can you please provide me a [mcve] that reproduces this?

Comment: sorry, just sorted the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do something with the `suffixes`, split the columns to a `MultiIndex`, and then unstack

```
Merged=pd.merge(Buy_MD,Sell_MD, on= ['ID','LocName','Sub-Group','Month'], how = 'inner', suffixes=('_buy', '_sell')

Merged.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(Merged.columns.str.rsplit('_').map(tuple), names=('key', 'transaction'))
```

> ```
> Merged = Merged.stack(level='transaction')
> ```

```
    transaction Deal    ID  Location
0   buy 130 5845    A
0   sell    155 9545    B
1   buy 155 5845    B
1   sell    155 345 C
2   buy 138 6245    C
2   sell    155 445 D
```

If you want to get rid of the `MultiIndex` you can do:

```
Merged.index = Merged.index.droplevel('transaction')
```